# How can change handle drag in dialog widget jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to change handle drag in this widget but I don't know how can do this

[image]

look at the above picture, I won't handle with the first section but I want to change it that element inside it.

Comment: Which widget/jQuery extension?

Comment: my mean was this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Include your jQuery and HTML/CSS

Comment: it's properly work but i want to just change handle  that drag it?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make an example on how to style the default area.  Adding the minimize and etc. is possible but not really recommended.  They're are better extensions for mini-winows than jQuery UI.

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" )
      .dialog()
      .parents(".ui-dialog")
      .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar")
      .css("background", "orange");
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div id="dialog" title="汉语/漢語">
 <p style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">some text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i explain my mean
i want to change handel that drag model to another element?
look at the below code
  jQuery(newmodal).dialog({autoOpen: false}).draggable({
            handle: ".panel-heading"
        });
i tried to solve it like this but it is wrong

Comment: i tried this code also
jQuery(newmodal).dialog({autoOpen: false,handle:".panel-heading"});
but still it doesn't working.

Comment: Add your full HTML and CSS and JavaScript then I would have some hope of understanding the problem.

Comment: this is my codes
http://s9.picofile.com/file/8290903326/change_handel_dialog_widget.zip.html

you can get it,and i hope you it useful